# How to setup MySQL for PHP on an already hosted website?

Tags: php, mysql, bluehost

I hope you are doing well.

We have fully developed our website *(this means everything, the domain, hosting, design is all done and the website is live and working)*. We chose Bluehost (bluehost.com) as our Hosting and Domain provider. Here's a snapshot of the panel I see (just in case for knowing the available menus) :

[image: bluehost snap]

Now we have some PHP pages with us, and we need to integrate MySQL with it. I have seen some videos regarding this, but all of them were for localhost & XAAMP. I just need to know how to connect MySQL with a published website, so we can code the database storing section in our PHP file.

Can you suggest any tutorials/articles reffering this problem?

I hope you understand my query. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Asking us to recommend tutorials is explicitly off topic here on SO. Hosting providers usualy have documentation on using databases and the image in your question also contains a mysql wizard. So, searching on your hosting provider's website, reaching out to their technical support - these are the right way to go forward.

Comment: Thanks, @Shadow, I'll contact them right away. Also I'll research more on the Wizard. Thanks again! 

Answer (score 0):

First you must create a database then somewhere in the menu-settings the blue host gives you information about username and password , then modify your php database connection file with host(probably is localhost),username,password,and database name

Comment: Thanks, @Mixalis, I'll check and see if I could use this method 